# when i run app in iPad simulater 5.1 there is a gap at the top of the display were the back ground image does not cover

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, ios-simulator

when i run app in the IPhone simulater 5.1 the default image loads up fine but when the app runs there is a gap at the top of the iPhone frame in the display of the IPad simulater (the size of a status bar in the iPhone simulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the view's frame in xib file, also change the windows and view background color to help you find the issue.

PS. in info.plist file, add "Status bar is initially hidden" .This maybe helpful.